# SQL Syntax errors encountered visual studio

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, mysql-workbench

I get this error:

> Error in SELECT clause: expression near '='. Missing FROM clause. Error in SELECT clause: expression near ','. Unable to parse query text.

```
 SELECT Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Conciliated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Criminal') AS criminalconciliated,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Repudiated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Criminal') AS criminalrepudiated,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Arbitrated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Criminal') AS criminalarbitrated,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Certified'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Criminal') AS criminalcertified,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Dismissed'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Criminal') AS criminaldismissed,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Forwarded'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Criminal') AS criminalforwarded,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Mediated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Criminal') AS criminalmediated,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Conciliated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Civil')    AS civilconciliated,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Repudiated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Civil')    AS civilrepudiated,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Arbitrated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Civil')    AS civilarbitrated,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Certified'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Civil')    AS civilcertified,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Dismissed'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Civil')    AS civilldismissed,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Forwarded'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Civil')    AS civilforwarded,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Mediated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Civil')    AS civilmediated,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Conciliated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Others')   AS othersconciliated,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Repudiated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Others')   AS othersrepudiated,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Arbitrated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Others')   AS othersarbitrated,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Certified'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Others')   AS otherscertified,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Dismissed'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Others')   AS othersdismissed,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Forwarded'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Others')   AS othersforwarded,
   Sum(subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Mediated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Others')   AS othersmediated
  FROM   subhearingsched
   JOIN cases
     ON ( subhearingsched.caseno = cases.caseno )
```

this is my query and when I run it in visual studio query builder it shows a parsing error but it works perfectly fine in mysql workbench and this also happened to my other queries that works perfectly fine in mysql workbench but not in visual studio.

Comment: Please include the *text* of the error message in the question: images of errors are not enough.

Comment: All the `subhearingsched.conclusion =` and  `cases.nature_of_case =` should be in `WHERE` clause

Comment: Error in SELECT clause: expression near '='.
Missing FROM clause.
Error in SELECT clause: expression near ','.
Unable to parse query text.

this is the error that appears every time i try to build the query

Comment: i but i need to specify it since different columns got different conditions, is there any alternatives?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: im trying to make a report of where sum of cases where conclusion = '[Conditiion]' and nature_of_case = 'Condition'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the syntax that you are using is MySQL dialect (and therefore works in MySQL workbench), but you better use the standard SQL by using 'CASE' in the 'SUM', like this:

```
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN subhearingsched.conclusion = 'Conciliated'
       AND cases.nature_of_case = 'Criminal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS criminalconciliated
  FROM   subhearingsched
   JOIN cases
     ON ( subhearingsched.caseno = cases.caseno )
```

Comment: i tried this before but it doesn't work too. it shows error


`Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'END'.
Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'FROM'.
Missing FROM clause.
Unable to parse query text.`

Comment: Then there is probably a typo in your query. What I would suggest is that you analyse it step by step: first select * from subhearingsched, then include the join then incluse a sum without the case statement, then add a simple case statement not involving the actual columns, then add 1 column and so on.... You should come back here with the first error you receive.